# Sum and recurrence for columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, calculated-columns

i have 3 columns: A has names, B has numbers, C has names. I want to see how many times MIKE and JANE appears in the table and how many times they met. The order of the columns is not fixed so i can modify the order of the columns (the names to be in columns A and B and the numbers in C) . Any help is welcomed.

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  |     A  |  B  |   C   |  D  |  E    |  F    |  G  | H      |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  | TRAINER|HOURS| CHILD |     |TRAINER| CHILD |HOURS|MEETINGS|
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  |  MIKE  |  2  | JANE  |     | MIKE  | JANE  | 10  |   2    |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  |  MIKE  |  5  | STEVE |     | MIKE  | STEVE |  7  |   2    |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  |  HARRY |  3  | JANE  |     | HARRY | JANE  |  3  |   1    |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  |  MIKE  |  8  | JANE  |     | HARRY | STEVE |  7  |   1    |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  |  MIKE  |  2  | STEVE |     |       |       |     |        |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
  |  HARRY |  7  | STEVE |     |       |       |     |        |
  -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Research the `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS` worksheet functions.

Comment: Also `SUMIF` / `SUMIFS` for the hours. `SUMPRODUCT` is also a good option, as long as you can specify the ranges (instead of whole columns). For the countif and sumif functions, that doesn't matter.

Comment: Also consider a pivot table with Trainer & Child as row variables and sum and count of hours as summary variables

Comment: hi, i am trying to keep it simple because my father is not good at excel :)

Comment: `COUNTIFS` for meetings, and `SUMIFS` for hours should be the easiest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to suggest a SUMPRODUCT option.  As other have mentioned there is also the SUMIF option.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$E2)*($C$2:$C$7=$F2)*$B$2:$B$7)
```

If you move your C column to B update the ranges in the formula accordingly.

Now the better option as other have suggested is:

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,$E2,$C$2:$C$7,$F2)
```

And I totally missed that you were looking for the number of meetings as opposed to the hours.  We can again use SUMPRODUCT with one less term or we can use COUNTIFS.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$E2)*($C$2:$C$7=$F2))
```

and the COUNTIFS method is

```
=SUMIFS($A$2:$A$7,$E2,$C$2:$C$7,$F2)
```

Comment: Hi, i made the a table with sumifs and countifs and i thank you for your time to answer.